# SQL how to make rows sum into new rows?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. I have a table like this

[image: table1]

What I want to do is order this table by the country. But I don't want multiple rows of the same country. Instead, I want the profit to be added by country, having this table has resulted:

[image: table2]

I don't know how can I do it.
I tried to do a GROUP BY like this

```
SELECT country,   
       sum(Profit) Profit,   
FROM table   
WHERE ...   
GROUP BY country
```

but I don't know what I should put as condition.

Comment: you should not use image only  .. you should also add  text sample ...  and the code you have tried

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove where keyword.  Then add 'Order by 1'
to the end your select. Then try.

```
SELECT country,
sum(Profit) Profit,
FROM table
GROUP BY country
Order by 1
```

Comment: İ am glad to help you.